# Замирание страницы при выполнении ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как исключить зависание страницы на время выполнения ajax-запроса?
Пробовал выключать-включать asynс, результата не дало.
Выполняю следующим образом:

```
$('.get_data').on('click',function(){

  var date=$(this).data('date');

  $.get('shift_data.php?date=' + date, function(msg) {
   $('#shift_data').html(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас всё тормозит не из-за запроса, который никакой нагрузки на интерфейс оказывать не должен, если он отправляется асинхронно. Вероятно, тормозит вставка данных: `$('#shift_data').html(msg);`

Comment: @АлексейУколов, спасибо за информацию! Может быть подскажете, каким образом можно разрешить проблему с медленной работой $('#shift_data').html(msg); ?

Comment: Нужно профилировать, сходу сказать что-то сложно. Скорее всего, у вас там очень много данных? Тогда можно попробовать вставлять их по частям через какие-то промежутки времени.

Comment: @АлексейУколов, да не, данных не много... а вот графики, которые строятся по этим данным, видимо, и тормозят процесс...

Answer (score 3):

Данные через ajax действительно грузились асинхронно.
Проблема была в js-скриптах, которые и тормозили весь процесс.